# ajax synchronous call with timeout

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, timeout, synchronous

New to ajax, so asking a very basic question.

-- Is there no way to make a Synchronous ajax call (async:false) with timeout set on it.?

http://www.ajaxtoolbox.com/request/

Timeout works perfect with Asynchronous call though in my application,
but for one particular scenario, I need a Synchronous call (the javascript should actually wait untill it hears back from the server), and this also works fine. But I need to handle a scenario where the sever could take long and a ajax timeout may be called.

Is there any other piece of standard documentation for ajax I could refer to?

Thanks

Comment: Anytime you might want a synchronous request, you should instead use an asynchronous one with what should happen afterwards in the callback.

Comment: I doubt it'll be implemented because synchronous XHR is officially deprecated, even though it's the only available solution for some cases like passing big dynamic data to content scripts in extensions before the page scripts are executed on document_start.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, during a synchronous ajax request, the browser is blocked and no javascript can be executed while the browser is blocked. Because of this, jQuery can't abort the ajax request after a set timeout because jQuery is javascript and javascript can't be executed while the browser is blocked. This is the primary flaw in synchronous ajax.

Anytime you might want a synchronous request, you should instead use an asynchronous one with what should happen afterwards in the callback, as shown below;

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'webservices.php',
    timeout: 200,
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {
        'cmd' : 'ping',
    },
    success : function(data, textStatus) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'webservices.php',
            async: false,
            dataType : 'json',
            data : {
                'cmd' : 'feedback',
                'data' : data,
                'userinfo' : window.dsuser
            },
            success : function(data, textStatus) {
                // success!
                Status("Thanks for the feedback, "
                    + window.dsuser.user + "!");
            }
        });
    },
    error : function(jqhdr, textStatus,
                     errorThrown) {
        Status("There was trouble sending your feedback. Please try again later");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to set a timeout on a synchronous call. When you set "async:false", I believe the browser actually locks up while waiting for the response. You should only use a synchronous request if you absolutely need to (because of the browser locking up).

Comment: Thanks!! thats what I am finding everywhere, Also - is there any standard api / documentation out there we can look into for ajax...?

Comment: You can look up the documentation for XmlHttpRequest, but it's probably better to use a library that abstracts out a bunch of the details. 

jQuery, for example, has a very good AJAX framework. That's the one I'm more familiar with.

jQUery's AJAX documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: true - I am using jquery too for this...and the doc does not say this explicitly for timeout (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)  and if you are familiar with validation framework, I am trying its 'remote:' feature to call the server for validation... the problem is that I validate the form with an onclick event of a button (not via submithandler) and after checking for form errors, I need to redirect to next page - in this case, it would redirect even before the remote returns back late (if the server is delayed)....so basically I want to wait for that remote call to get completed

Comment: Ah, I haven't tried the validation framework. Off the top of my head, I'd say that you should put the redirection code into your "success" handler (or equivalent). This way, you'll only redirect once the asynchronous call completes.

Comment: hmm... well to make things more complicated I am also validating on the onkeyup event on that field... so in that case since it is the same remote validation being called, the redirecting on success will not be a good idea. But you did answer my initial question though... that timeout is not for synchronous calls... that helped me enough . I might need to explore the validation framework I guess.. Thanks!