# How can I make JQuery.ajax synchronous with a timeout?

Tags: jquery

I have a calendar with data that is on the server.  When the user moves forward by a month, I might (based on previous actions) need to fetch that data BEFORE I can display that month.

My code handles the failure (404), but I can't make it deal with a timeout, because the call is synchronous.  I know that timeout is ignored when the .ajax call is synchronous, what I want to know is how do I make a synchronous wait around the async call?  I want properly deal with the timeout, but short of a spin loop, I don't know how to elegantly do this in javascript.

I have a modal dialog over the page to stop clicks, I simply need to hold the user back until I can render the next month, or if a timeout happens, to prevent them moving to that month, since the data on that month isn't valid.

I don't quite see how the jquery code is pulling this off...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ajax synchronous call with timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195259/ajax-synchronous-call-with-timeout)

Comment: Would setInterval do what you're hoping?  Or is that what you're referring to as a 'spin loop'?

Comment: Use an asynchronous ajax call - not hanging the browser is a **good thing**.

Comment: I saw that one and there isn't a good answer on it yet either.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to keep the screen locked out until either success or failure.  It sounds like you want to make the AJAX call aysnch and register callback functions with JQuery [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (for example, the on error event):

> error(jqXHR, textStatus,
>   errorThrown)Function  A function to be
>   called if the request fails. The
>   function receives three arguments: The
>   jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
>   XMLHttpRequest) object, a string
>   describing the type of error that
>   occurred and an optional exception
>   object, if one occurred. Possible
>   values for the second argument
>   (besides null) are "timeout", "error",
>   "abort", and "parsererror". This is an
>   Ajax Event. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   error setting can accept an array of
>   functions. Each function will be
>   called in turn. Note: This handler is
>   not called for cross-domain script and
>   JSONP requests.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your problem it sounds like you should be able to resolve this issues by nesting the AJAX calls such that the second one doesn't fire until the response to the first one comes back:

```
$.get('first.php',
    function(firstresponse){
        // do stuff with first response as needed

        $.get('second.php',
            function(secondresponse){
                // do stuff with second response as needed
            }

        );
    }
);
```