# $.ajax call with async:false and timeout expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, timeout

I've a web application which calls a webservice with ajax. This webservices returns me the configuraiton for my app, so the ajax call needs to be set at {async:false}.
Everything works fine when my server is up, but in the case it's not, my browser just freezes. Even if I set a timeout in my ajax call setup.
I've a error handler function which is never called even if the timeout is passed.

Someone has ever been confronted to that situation ?

@Edit : My problem can be solved by doing asynchronous call

Comment: Ok, i've found sort of an answer in that post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195259/ajax-synchronous-call-with-timeout

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest.  Good luck ;)

Comment: Why not doing it asynchronously and have whatever code you need to run in the `success` callback function?

Comment: I am _not_ one of these "OMG USE ASYNC FOR EVERYTHING" idiots. Still, the logical implication "this webservices returns me the configuraiton for my app, so the ajax call needs to be set at {async:false}" is invalid as far as I can tell. One should have nothing to do with the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the browser is single threaded it would be better to process the config 
returned in the callback success, and handle any errors in the error callback.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mydomain.com/url",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  data: $.param( $("Element or Expression") ),

  complete: function() {
    //called when complete
  },

  success: function() {
    //called when successful
 },

  error: function() {
    //called when there is an error
  },
});
```

Comment: Yep, that's what i'm going to do ^^

Comment: Which browser? He never stated what his browser is. In actual fact, most browsers these days can handle synchronous requests _just fine_, without locking up. After all, they do it OK for the standard requests, don't they?? Regardless, this doesn't even come close to answering the question posed.

Comment: I didn't specify the browser indeed, I work with IE (because my app use ActiveX...). Anyway, this answer enables me to face my problem on another point of view and so, to solve it.

Comment: @Tomalak: James' point is that there is no reason to use synchronous calls, async calls are just as easy and don't cause freezes. Many browsers will freeze up while a synchronous call is active. That some don't is moot, you can't ignore the fact that your users will use different browsers.

Comment: @Theo: And my point is that browsers haven't frozen up during requests since the late 90s. There is no reason to use asynchronous calls, especially when it needlessly complicates your logic.

Comment: Try this at home: do a synchronous _Ajax_ call. While the data loads, try to do anything else that will run JavaScript (for example click a button that triggers some JavaScript code). No matter which browser you use the second action will not run until the Ajax call has completed. That is what is meant by the browser freezing up.